# Multiple DB contexts, single database, publish website

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am using SmarterASP for hosting my website. My website is built using ASP.NET Webforms with Entity Framework and ASP.NET Identity for security login.

However I do have one problem I cannot figure out.

My app has 2 DbContexts, one for Identity (`ApplicationDbContext`) and one for everything else (`DbContext`). I have recently updated Identity to version 2. After publishing when I tried to login I am getting the below error.

> There is already an object named 'ASPNETROLES' in the database

But the `DbContext` is working fine.

1. Both migration .cs files are present, named as above and appear in a `DbContext` folder and the project builds and runs locally fine.
2. Both contexts point to the same db and have one connection string in `web.config`.
3. Migration files are separated into folders for each context

Any ideas as to where else I could look to solve this? At this point I don't know it's a SmarterASP publish problem or something foul in my project.

Thanks!

Comment: `There is already an object named 'ASPNETROLES' in the database` Pretty self explanatory, your database server already have a database with table named `ASPNETROLES`.

Comment: @12seconds Yes!! but now I need to upgrade those tables to ASP.NET Identity v2. In local its upgraded and working fine, when I try to publish the same code it showing this error